# MongoDB: Combine documents from two collections

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

So I have two different `MongoDB` collections and I want to combine the both to output something. I understand it's possible through `mapReduce` jobs, but that requires storing into a third collection. I don't want to store these documents. All I want is these consolidated documents to come as the output of a query.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What would be it's real world application?!, if you just want the output, and because you are using Python driver, just iterate over the two collections.

Comment: Hey @Abderrahimben, in a real world application I want to optimise fetching these documents. Iterating over both collections wouldn't solve that.

Comment: I asked this question somewhere and i got an answer which pretty much says that Mongo doesnt have Join operation, not posting it as answer because im not skilled enough to be sure.